# Fixed position footer moving in mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, mobile

I have a position:fixed footer on a huge form that has been moving after opening the keyboard and scrolling a bit. It happens because the address bar shows/hides, and the footer moves the same height as the address bar, going up and down. The elements are actually visible where they should be, but touch events and inspecting via Chrome dev tools shows it is misplaced.

This screenshot shows this weird behavior:
[remote device inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rc2X.png)

I have tried forcing hide/show after focus in/out of inputs. I also tried the footer inside the container and after it. (and some other stupid ideas that didn't help). I thought about changing the element in every scroll, but this page has a form with 150 questions (some with sub-questions) and already is quite heavy.

Any ideas?